Generate a binary pattern that shifts the bit to right
Here is the pattern I have been trying to generate for a 8x8 matrix display such that each led being lit represents a particular count:
00000001
00000010
00000100
00001000
00010000
00100000
01000000
10000000
10000001
10000010
10000100
10001000
10010000
10100000
11000000
11000001   
...

and so on..... until all the bits become 1.
I was able to shift the the bits from right to left, such that 0x01 becomes 0x80, but how do I hold the MSB in its place and start shifting a new bit from LSB(from right side) as described above?
void MAX7219_SendData(uint8_t address, uint8_t data) {
    uint8_t txData[2] = {address, data};
    MAX7219_CS_Low();
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&MAX7219_SPI_INSTANCE, txData, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    MAX7219_CS_High();
}

I use the above function to talk MAX7219 IC via SPI.
I am using MAX7219 matrix display to display a pattern.
The MAX7219 contains 8 registers that control eight rows of the display( 8x8 display).
For example, if I send 00000001 along with the register address as a 16bit word, it would lit up the top - right LED.So, if I send a binary sequence as shown above, it would like as if light is passing through all the LED’s. Once top row is filled, same should start in the next row and so on…
In essence, the matrix will show whatever is put in its registers( each of 8 bits). The refresh frequency is around 500hz as mentioned in the data sheet if it is something that can be helpful.

The code for generating the bit pattern would be much more relevant for your question than the code for sending it via SPI. What have you tried so far?

What is the data you are dealing with? Do you have a counter and need to generate the corresponding pattern? Do you have current pattern and need to generate the successor pattern? Please edit your question to show a MCVE

Neither SPI not embedded in general has nothing to do with your question. This is a purely bit pattern algorithm question.

Please [edit] and show your non working code and remove the  MAX7219_SendData function which is totally unrelated to your question.

"I was able to shift the the bits from right to left, such that 0x01 becomes 0x80, but how do I hold the MSB in its place and start shifting a new bit from LSB(from right side) as described above?": maybe use two variables? I suggest you start designing your algorithm with a piece of paper and a pencil.

There are 37 possible patterns. Just hardcode a lookup table.

@n.m.couldbeanAI according to my code below (see live demo) I believe it's only 36 patterns (because the OP does not need all-zeroes.)

I have edited the question to have a better picture..

You can use another variable (val_base in the code below), to hold the base pattern on which you will apply the shifts of the current bit.
In the code below I used 2 nested loops: one for iterating over the groups of patterns (in each group specific bits on the left are 1), and one for shifting the current bit.
Note that the number of iterations in the inner loop depends on the outer loop (because every time we advance to the next group, less shifts should be applied).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main() {
    uint8_t val_base = 0;
    for (int iGroup = 0; iGroup < 8; ++iGroup) {  // iterate over the 8 groups of patterns
        for (int iShift = 0; iShift < (8-iGroup); ++iShift) { // iterate on the patterns in each group
            uint8_t val = (1 << iShift) + val_base;
            printf("%08B\n", val);
        }
        val_base |= (1 << (8 - iGroup - 1));    // for next iteration
    }
}

Output:
00000001
00000010
00000100
00001000
00010000

...

11111010
11111100
11111101
11111110
11111111

Live demo
Note:
In production code the most efficient thing you can do is probably to create a hard-coded lookup table with all the patterns.
You can still use the code above to generate this lookup table easily.

pro tip: with newer C standard or newer glibc you can do printf("%08B\n", val) instead of print_uint8_as_binary.

@KamilCuk nice! updated my answer with it.

I'll offer a different looped answer based on the way that old style bitmapped sprites used to be moved. I though it was quite neat until I saw the incredible top bit twiddling answer by Eric. IRL lookup table is fastest.
#include <stdio.h>

void shiftbits()
{
   int bits, k;
   k = bits = 0;
   printf("%2i : %08B \n", ++k, bits);
   for (int i = 8; i; i--)
   {
      int mask = 3;
      bits |= 1;
      printf("%2i : %08B \n", ++k, bits);
      for (int j = i-1 ; j; j--)
      {
          bits ^= mask;
          mask = mask + mask;
          printf("%2i : %08B \n", ++k, bits);
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
  shiftbits();
  return 0;
}

Its inelegance is that the printf occurs once in each of the nested loops.
I vaguely recall nixie tube based event counters that used this sort of rule from way back (late 60's?). Fat vacuum tubes which had a ring of round rod electrodes viewed edge.

There's another way to write this that, to me, is more mechanical than mystical. (My brain has a hard time tracking which variables are increasing, which are decreasing and how their values relate to one-another.)
The following seems to be a more direct expression of the desired goal. Tastes differ.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main( void ) {
    uint8_t pwr = 0x80, val = 0, trv = 0;

    do {
        do {
            printf( "%08B\n", val | trv );
            trv = trv ? trv << 1 : 1; // shift left OR seed first '1'
        } while( trv < pwr ); // until shifted maximally
        val |= trv, trv = 0; // burn it in and reset to zero
    } while( ( pwr >>= 1 ) != 0 ); // shifting left boundary to the right
    printf( "%08B\n", val ); // spill the final version

    return 0;
}

This can be seen running here

I decided to find the movable bit - set bit that has unset bit to its left, and if there is none, handle edge cases (set the least significant bit, or roll over).
Here is the implementation and test:
char bitpattern_increment(char bits) {
char retval_new_pattern = 0;
int movable_bit_pos = 0;

if (bits == 0) {
    retval_new_pattern = 0x01;
    goto end;
}

for (; movable_bit_pos < 7; movable_bit_pos++) {
    if ((bits >> movable_bit_pos) & 0x01) {
        if (((bits >> (movable_bit_pos + 1)) & 0x01) == 0x00) {
            retval_new_pattern = bits & ~(0x01 << movable_bit_pos);
            retval_new_pattern |= (0x01 << (movable_bit_pos + 1));
            goto end;
        }
    }
}

if (bits == (char)0xFF) {
        retval_new_pattern = 0x00;
        goto end;
}

retval_new_pattern = bits | 0x01;

end: return retval_new_pattern;
}

Tested it the following way (starting with 0xFF to test edge cases easily):
char bitpattern = 0xFF;
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    bitpattern = bitpattern_increment(bitpattern);
    std::bitset<8> bitpattern_set(bitpattern);
    std::cout << bitpattern_set << std::endl;
}

Test output:
00000000
00000001
00000010
00000100
00001000
00010000
00100000
01000000
10000000
10000001
10000010
10000100
10001000
10010000
10100000
11000000
11000001
11000010
11000100
11001000
11010000
11100000
11100001
11100010
11100100
11101000
11110000
11110001
11110010
11110100
11111000
11111001
11111010
11111100
11111101
11111110
11111111
00000000
00000001
00000010


the question is tagged C not C++ (std::bitset, std::cout). Also using goto is a code smell.


It doesn't matter if it's C or C++, the code that is of interest to the author is valid C code. I used C++ to test it. It will work with C. 2) "Using goto is a code smell" statement is a nonsense on its own. Code with goto can be faster and simpler to read, if implemented correctly, also makes memory management easier in certain cases. Like every tool, it has proper and improper use cases. 3) The author is free to take my code and adjust it to their own code tastes.


"code smell" does not mean it is always bad. It just means that usually there are better solutions. I think this applies to goto in general. I can hardly remember cases where using it improved the code. But of course it is up to you to use it as you see fit.
